# Can connect to some but not all localhost OPC Servers

Tags: opc

I am trying to connect to a **local** OPC server. It is one of 7 OPC servers on the computer. I can connect to all the other servers except for this one.

As far as I can tell I have the server-specific DCOM settings wide open. Is there anything I could be overlooking as to why I cannot connect to this server?

Again this is a **local** server, not a remote computer.

By can't connect I mean I can see the OPC server in an OPC client, so opcenum is working - but I get a "OPCServer.WinCC. CoCreateInstanceEx: : 80070005 (Access Denied)" error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with Unitronic OPC Server on Windows 10. The OPC client is SCADA Reliance 4. The OPC Server runs as local on the same PC as Reliance. The problem is that the user requires to run Reliance with OPC server with limited privileges. Unitronic OPC server runs only with increased privileges because it is unable to operate with lower privileges. If an OPC client runs with a lower privilege than an OPC server, it is unable to establish a connection because of the restrictions. For these reasons, user must run the OPC client using the "Run As Administrator" option and the connection is successfully established in this case.